# Creating Dockerfile with Environmental Variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a docker image that will run a command for the users. The command will need a number of variable entries, specific for the person running it. I tried simply creating it with the variables and, because the command couldn't be run upon build, the process wouldn't complete. I then tried using the '${varname:-possible value}, and I got a little further.

I'm guessing part of the problem may be that some of the variables are URLs, since the folder name, also a variable, is being accepted. I did try adding escape characters ('\') to all the special characters in the URL and all that did was get me a 'bad substitution' error instead.

What then, should I change in my syntax?

```
RUN /usr/bin/java -jar export.jar calendar \
    --output /var/www \
    --format public \
    --restUri ${one_uri:-http://my.site:8080/subdir/restservice} \
    --daysForward ${days_forward:-30}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly get if your users is building their own Dockerfile or they are using your docker image directly, but if they create their own, then you can use `ONBUILD` to run a command that will when the user `docker build` their container.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#onbuild

*else*

you can just specify your own defaults like this

```
ENV days_forward "30"
```

and then they can easily overwrite that environment variable when they run your container.

Comment: Thanks. I found that worked well. Ended up creating a script, then calling the script. I was worried that, once I set the environmental variables, they couldn't be changed by the user.